# No Inode space!; How to delete Magento sessions folder's contents?

Tags: php, session, memory, folder

Hopefully, someone can help me,

A Magento website I'm managing keeps going down, I've determined it to be the fact that it has used up all of the Inode space on the server.

The output to df -i is below..

```
/dev/vda1 3932160 3932160 0 100% /
none 506035 2 506033 1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev 503322 402 502920 1% /dev
tmpfs 506035 323 505712 1% /run
none 506035 4 506031 1% /run/lock
none 506035 1 506034 1% /run/shm
none 506035 2 506033 1% /run/user
```

As you can see it is quite clearly the top one with the problem. As it's a Magento site, I do have a feeling it's the var/session folder. I have changed to it's directory within PUTTY (the session folder) and typed in 'ls' and the list seems to go on forever. I should delete them all, no?

So my file system is out of inodes.. and the session folder I believe is the culprit, How can i go about resolving this? I.e what code do i input to delete said session files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't delete all sessions, start with the older ones first. Since the quote is valid for 30 days you could try going with that. In your `var/session` folder.

```
find . -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will find all files older then 30 days and delete them. Optionally you can run this as a cronjob, do remember to replace the dot with the full path to the session files `/path/to/magento/var/sessions/*`

Also check the size of the `report` folder and the individual log files. Those tend to run up as well.

And the `log_` tables in Magento can become quite large which would consume quite some disk space. You can truncate the following tables.

```
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
```

To turn off writing to these tables all together follow [this tutorial](http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/). It's actually also beneficial for performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I will give this a shot first thing tomorrow. Along with the answer below from fschmengler.

Answer (score 2):

First verify that it's really a problematic amount of session files:

```
ls -U1 | wc -l
```

is a fast command to give you the number of files in the current directory

Then only delete old session files, otherwise you'll log out all customers and empty the cart of all guests (see answer by Sander Mangel)

Also have a look at other directories in `var`. This command shows you the used inodes of all directories in var:

```
du --inodes --max-depth=1 ./var
```

You might also have a big number of files in `var/report` (but that also means, the shop throws lots of exceptions and you have more problems...).

Answer (score 0):

first go to the `var/session` folder of the magento root directory

```
find . -name "*" -print | xargs rm -rf
```

This command will delete all the data in the current folder without prompting you.