# Customer's sessions are mixed

Tags: session, customer-session

Sometimes I'm login as one user and in some pages I see the name of other user that I've never used to login in that computer.

this happens in different pages, and don't happens always.

Any idea of what can generate this issue ?

Comment: Jacr did you solve this? And how?

Comment: Yes, this is related to cache, I have removed some blocks from cache

Comment: What cache? Full page caching or redis? And what blocks did you remove and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header.phtml file you should use this to print the user name

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?>
```

Then, you can override the block 'Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome' if you wanna customize your message.

this happens when you use "Full Page Cache" because by default, magento exclude some blocks of the full page cache, and the block 'welcome' is one of they. if you are using customization code and message, the user name will be cached too, and other users will see different user names in this section.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using some **Full page cache**, disable it or set it to `NO`

2) Clear your Magento sessions, see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82024/no-inode-space-how-to-delete-magento-sessions-folders-contents).

3) Clear all `Magento` and `Browser` cache.